# Disable the text box from being accessed by the user in calendar_date_select

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a date picker 
<%= calendar_date_select_tag "from_date", nil, :embedded => false, :year_range => 10.years.ago..0.years.ago, :valid_date_check => "date < (new Date()).stripTime()" %>
The problem is as it is not embedded a text box appears and it makes the users to change it. How can I make it off so that only this datepicker can change its value?

I am using rails in xp
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried :popup => 'force'